# Scala Lift Rest API responses HTML

Tags: scala, rest, lift

I'm currently working on a Rest Api using Lift as Framework. 
Most of the requests are using Json as return type which works fine:

```
serve ("api" / "item" prefix {
    case _ :: Nil JsonGet _ => {
      if (checkKey(S.params("api_key").mkString)) Item.newItem(S.params("item_id").mkString, S.params("api_key").mkString)
    }
  })
```

Now i want to add a function which returns plain html which is stored in a mysql db. So basicly i want to return a String back to the Resthelper. 
I tried something like this but it didn't compile:

```
serve {
    case "itemDesc" :: itemnum :: _ => {
      Item.getDescription(itemnum)
    }
  }
```

Maybe I'm stupid but i couldn't find anything in the Lift "Cookbook"

Update:

```
serve { 
    case "itemDesc" :: AsInt(itemnum) :: _ XmlGet _ => { 
      Item.getDescription(itemnum) 
    } 
  }
```

I tried this to fool lift by selling html as XML. It compiled but didn't work at the end.
Obviously it's not possible to respond a normal String back from a RestHelper.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give back `Box[LiftResponse]`.

So In that case It'd be `Full(PlainTextResponse(Item.getDescription(itemnum))`.

I would also add implicit conversion from `LiftResponse -> Box[LiftResponse]`

Comment: Thanks that worked. But now i have the problem that the html which is returned by the Item.getDecription(itemnum) function is printed to the browser as html not as interpreted html. It seems that the content is wrapped in a html pre tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
serve {
    case "itemDesc" :: AsInt(itemnum) :: _ XmlGet _ => {
      Full(PlainTextResponse(Item.getDescription(itemnum), ("Content-Type" -> "text/html") :: Nil, 200))
    }
  }
```

Is the right Answer. I had to add the content type to PlainTextResponse to get the HTML parsed. With this snipped i can have my rest api work like a charm and add a function that returnes plain text with content type html back to the browser.

Comment: Hum that i a bit hacky solution. Look here:
http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.http.LiftResponse
And extend "Known Subclasses". In this case I'd use:
XhtmlResponse. But problem is that Item.getDescription returns String and this goes around html parser and its easy to introduce XSS here. You should use Snippets, Css transforms and all that Lift goodness in this case. Rest is better for getting json/xml or pushing some data/state to server.